# IDL:How to divide FOR loop in N parts for parallel execution?

Tags: parallel-processing, idl-programming-language

I have a time consuming loop of length 300.  I would like to execute in parallel.

Pseudocode:

```
for t=0, 300 do begin
output_data[t] = function(input_data(t))
endfor
```

• The function() for each iteration is completely the same
• The input_data(t)) is stored in a file

Is possible divide the 300 iterations in to K parallel processes (where k is the CPU number)?
I found split_fot.pro but if I understand correctly it is for divide the different processes in the same nth cicle of loop.
How can I do?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I have some routines in my library that you could use to do something like the following:

```
pool = obj_new('MG_Pool', n_processes=k)
x = indgen(300)
output_data = pool->map('my_function', x)
```

Here, `my_function` would need to accept an argument `i`, get the data associated with index `I`, and apply `function` to it. The result would then be put into `output_data[i]`.

You can specify the number of processes you want to use for the `pool` object with the `N_PROCESSES` keyword or it will just automatically use the number of cores you have available.

The code is in [my library](https://github.com/mgalloy/mglib), check the `src/multiprocessing` directory. See the `examples/multiprocessing` directory for some examples of using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IDL_IDLBridge` along with object arrays
to create multiple child processes.

Child processes do not inherit variables from main process,
so you may want to use `SHMMAP`, `SHMVAR`, `SHMUNMAP`
to share variables across child processes,
or use `SETVAR` method of `IDL_IDLBridge` if memory is not a problem.

As an example, below I create 5 child processes to distribute the for-loop:

```
dim_input = size(input_data, /dim) ; obtain the data dimension
dim_output = size(output_data, /dim)
shmmap, dimension=dim_input, get_name=seg_input   ; set the memory segment
shmmap, dimension=dim_output, get_name=seg_output 
shared_input = shmvar(seg_input)
shared_output = shmvar(seg_output)
shared_input[0] = input_data ; assign data to the shared variable
                             ; shared_data[0, 0] if data is 2d
shared_output[0] = output_data

; initialize child processes
procs = objarr(5)
for i = 0, 4 do begin
    procs[i] = IDL_IDLBridge(output='')
    procs[i].setvar, 'istart', i*60
    procs[i].setvar, 'iend', (i+1)*60 - 1
    procs[i].setvar, 'seg_input', seg_input
    procs[i].setvar, 'seg_output', seg_output
    procs[i].setvar, 'dim_input', dim_input
    procs[i].setvar, 'dim_output', dim_output
    procs[i].execute, 'shmmap, seg_input, dimension=dim_input'
    procs[i].execute, 'shmmap, seg_output, dimension=dim_output'
    procs[i].execute, 'shared_input = shmvar(seg_input)'
    procs[i].execute, 'shared_output = shmvar(seg_output)'
endfor

; execute the for-loop asynchronously
for i = 0, 4 do begin
    procs[i].execute, 'for t=istart, iend do ' + $
                      'shared_output[t] = function(shared_input[t])', $
                      /nowait
endfor

; wait until all child processes are idle
repeat begin
    n_idle = 0
    for i = 0, 4 do begin
    case procs[i].status() of
        0: n_idle++
        2: n_idle++
        else:
    endcase
  endfor
  wait, 1
endrep until (n_idle eq 5)

; cleanup child processes
for i = 0, 4 do begin
    procs[i].cleanup
    obj_destroy, procs[i]
endfor

; assign output values back to output_data
; unmap the shared variable
output_data = shared_output[0]
shmunmap, seg_input
shmunmap, seg_output
shared_input = 0
shared_output = 0
```

You may also want to optimize your function for multi-processing.
Lastly, to prevent multiple accesses to the memory segment,
you can use `SEM_CREATE`, `SEM_LOCK`, `SEM_RELEASE`, `SEM_DELETE`
functions/procedures provided by IDL.